# Add empty cell to HTML table when column missing from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a XML file and I'm populating a HTML table with the data in the XML using jQuery. The XML file has the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Row>
    <Patologia>Alzheimer</Patologia>
    <Molecula>Galantamina</Molecula>
    <Nombre_Comercial>RAZADYNE®</Nombre_Comercial>
    <Fecha_Exp>2017-06</Fecha_Exp>
    <Propietario>JANSSEN PHARMS</Propietario>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Patologia>Alzheimer</Patologia>
    <Molecula>Liraglutida</Molecula>
    <Nombre_Comercial>Victoza®</Nombre_Comercial>
    <Propietario>NOVO NORDISK INC</Propietario>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Patologia>Alzheimer</Patologia>
    <Nombre_Comercial>ARICEPT ODT®</Nombre_Comercial>
    <Fecha_Exp>2018-03</Fecha_Exp>
    <Propietario>EISAI INC</Propietario>
</Row>
```

I have the following JavaScript:

```js
function showData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test2.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $('#mainTable').empty();
            var fila = $(xml).find("Row");
            var tabla = $("#mainTable");

            var row = $(tabla[0].insertRow(-1));

            fila.eq(0).children().each(function () {
                var headerCell = $("<th />");
                headerCell.html(this.nodeName);
                row.append(headerCell);
            });

            $(fila).each(function () {
                row = $(tabla[0].insertRow(-1));
                $(this).children().each(function () {
                    var cell = $("<td />");
                    cell.html($(this).text());
                    row.append(cell);
                });
            });

            var thead = tabla.find("thead");
            var thRows = tabla.find("tr:has(th)");

            thead = $("<thead />").prependTo(tabla);

            var copy = thRows.clone(true).appendTo("thead");
            thRows.remove();

            $("#mainTable td:empty").append("epale");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that in the XML file some rows are missing a column or two. When filling the table using the jQuery code it messes up the columns when a column is missing from the XML. 
How can I add an empty cell when a row is missing?

I hope I was able to explain the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.